# How to create schema without application restart in spring-boot?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, stored-procedures, multi-tenant, java-stored-procedures

I am implementing multi-tenancy in my application..switching between database is working fine, but here challenge is I want to create a new schema whenever user is registering to my application. Without application restart is it possible to create new schema programmatically ?

After research I got to know that using stored-procedure we can achieve this..but I wanted to know is there any better approach where we can create schema without application restart..

Comment: The creation of schema during runtime is not a problem. The question is what you want to do after the creation?

Comment: I am implementing multi-tenancy based on different database approach ..when user registration I want to create schema for high level isolation of data

Comment: Yes and then? Do you want to create a datasource for this schema?

Comment: that will be taken cared by multi-tenancy implementation.. so switching between different data source is not a problem.. any how that is working..

Comment: I have referred this http://anakiou.blogspot.com/2015/08/multi-tenant-application-with-spring.html for implemnation

Comment: So then go ahead and create the schema with the stored procedure